# Cmd+Shift+4 Simulation in Cocoa/Obj-C Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, keyboard, simulation

Here is my code:

```
CGEventSourceRef src =
CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);

CGEventRef cmdd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x37, true);
CGEventRef cmdu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x37, false);
CGEventRef sftd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x38, true);
CGEventRef sftu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x38, false);
CGEventRef fourd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x15, true);
CGEventRef fouru = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x15, false);

CGEventSetFlags(fourd, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand); //NO idea why this is here.
CGEventSetFlags(fouru, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand); //NO idea why this is here.


CGEventTapLocation loc = kCGHIDEventTap; // kCGSessionEventTap also works
CGEventPost(loc, cmdd); //Cmd down
CGEventPost(loc, sftd); //Shift down
CGEventPost(loc, fourd);   //4 down
CGEventPost(loc, cmdu); //Cmd up
CGEventPost(loc, sftu); //Shift up
CGEventPost(loc, fouru);   //4 up

CFRelease(cmdd);
CFRelease(cmdu);
CFRelease(sftd);
CFRelease(sftu);
CFRelease(fourd);
CFRelease(fouru);
CFRelease(src);
```

}

Can anyone tell me why this won't work? It makes a button press execute the command Cmd+Shft+4 and allows the user to execute the screenshot function.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some flags set for the cmd/shift/4 keystrokes.

> ```
> CGEventSourceRef src = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
>
> CGEventRef cmdd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x37, true);
> CGEventRef cmdu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x37, false);
> CGEventSetFlags(cmdd, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
> CGEventSetFlags(cmdu, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand);
> CGEventRef sftd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x38, true);
> CGEventRef sftu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x38, false);
> CGEventSetFlags(sftd, kCGEventFlagMaskShift);
> CGEventSetFlags(sftu, kCGEventFlagMaskShift);
> CGEventRef fourd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x15, true);
> CGEventRef fouru = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, 0x15, false);
> CGEventSetFlags(fourd, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand ^ kCGEventFlagMaskShift);
> CGEventSetFlags(fouru, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand ^ kCGEventFlagMaskShift);
>
> CGEventTapLocation loc = kCGHIDEventTap; // kCGSessionEventTap also works
> CGEventPost(loc, sftd); //Shift down
> CGEventPost(loc, cmdd); //Cmd down
> CGEventPost(loc, fourd);   //4 down
> CGEventPost(loc, fouru);   //4 up
> CGEventPost(loc, sftu); //Shift up
> CGEventPost(loc, cmdu); //Cmd up
>
> CFRelease(cmdd);
> CFRelease(cmdu);
> CFRelease(sftd);
> CFRelease(sftu);
> CFRelease(fourd);
> CFRelease(fouru);
> CFRelease(src);
> ```